# How to change Scene properties in JavaFX via FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

The task is to change appearance: add some more elements to the window when a button is clicked. It seems that I can handle this without FXML (see the code below), but I really like the FXML technology and want to use it.

Could you please advise how I can translate this code in FXML to have the same result?

```
public class TestChangeWindow extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    Stage mWindow;
    Button button;
    ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
    VBox layout;
    Scene scene;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        mWindow = primaryStage;
        mWindow.setTitle("Some title");

        button = new Button("Add button above");
        button.setOnAction(this);
        layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.getChildren().add(button);

        scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 300);

        mWindow.setScene(scene);
        mWindow.show();
    }

    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        buttons.add(new Button("Clone"));
        layout = new VBox(10);

        for (Button buttonsFTL : buttons) {
            layout.getChildren().add(buttonsFTL);
        }
        layout.getChildren().add(button);
        scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 300);
        mWindow.setScene(scene);
        mWindow.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show some efforts to get some help, start by checking some tutorials like [this one](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/javafx/fxml/javafx-fxml-tutorial/) and downloading [JavaFX Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html)

Comment: That's an easy one. Since you react to a button click on a button in the scene shown in the stage in the event handler, you can be sure that stage is shown making `mWindow.show()` unnecessary. Furthermore note that you create the exact same scene, but with one more button, which means recreating the scene is unnecessary and you can just do `layout.getChildren().add(layout.getChildren().size()-1, new Button("Clone"))` which means this can easily done in a event handler in the fxml controller and accessing the `Window` or the `Scene` is just unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you so much - i got it, So I keep my main sketch in fxml, and if I need to add some, I just do it with controller in plain Java, and add it to the layout, and all the css and rules for the layout will be applied to the added element. That's briliant, thank you for your help.